# OR operator doesn't evaluate both statements, only 1

Tags: c++, boolean-operations

```
std::ifstream file_1(argv[1]);
std::ifstream file_2(argv[2]);
...
std::string dummy_1;
std::string dummy_2;
...
while(std::getline(file_1, dummy_1) || std::getline(file_2, dummy_2)) // the problem
{
  ...
}
```

The condition behaves like the OR operator is evaluating the option on the right only if the file on the left reach the end (returning a FALSE) and it doesn't evaluate them at the same time.

I know that the evaluation of a statement has nothing to do with the operator itself or with its own precedence rules, but my program it's not supposed to work like I'm imaging with both statements being evaluated at the same time ?

Comment: No, it is supposed to evaluate the LHS first, and only evaluate the RHS if the LHS evaluates to false, as you observe. This is called "short-circuit" evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OR operator is a short circuit operator, meaning that if one side evaluates to true the other side is never actually executed. If your intention is to have both sides of the OR evaluated then you might want to reconsider how your code is written.

Comment: i can't break this behaviour ? to be sure to keep 2 files on the same index i have to use an iterator ?

Comment: @user1802174 You could work around it by changing the expression to `!std::getline(file_1, dummy_1) && !std::getline(file_2, dummy_2)`. It will exit the loop if _one_ of the `std::getline` calls fails.

Answer (score 4):

That's how boolean OR operates in most programming languages; this behavior is called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

If you want to always evaluate both expressions, do so individually and then use the results inside the conditional:

```
std::getline(file_1, dummy_1);
std::getline(file_2, dummy_2);
if (file_1 || file_2) { ... }
```

Comment: good idea, but makes my program a little bit too complex for just an iteration over 2 files ...

Comment: @user1802174: Why is this "too complex"?

Comment: @user1802174: It makes the program more verbose, not complex. But you don't really have a choice: it's either this or changing the operator inside the conditional, which is IMHO misleading and makes the code prone to having bugs introduced.

Comment: @shuttle87 I was using the word "complex" with the meaning that this will become more verbose.

Comment: @Jon this is a good point after all ... why no one is suggesting the use of iterators ?

Comment: @user1802174: What kind of iterators?

Answer (score 1):

This is called short circuiting. Please check the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/expr/shortcircuit.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitwise logical operator '|' to guarantee the execution of both expressions. But even then, the execution order is not defined in C or C++. (Java would execute from left to right).

`if (readline(this_line) | readline(that_line) ) ...`
which ever line is read first, is arbitrary.